# when two vectors do not lie on the same line, how does their combination fill the whole two-dimensional plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the book [https://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/ila5/indexila5.html](https://math.mit.edu/%7Egs/linearalgebra/ila5/indexila5.html), the author mentions that

> The vectors cv lie along a line. When w is not on that line, the combinations cv + dw fill the whole two-dimensional plane.

Is there a proof for this statement? Intuitively, my brain thinks that there might be a vector on the xy plane that is not a result of any combination of $cv + dw$

Later in the next sentence he also mentions that

> Starting from 4 vectors  $u, v, w, z$ in four-dimensional space, their combinations $cu + dv + ew + fz$ are likely to fill the space, but not always. The vectors and their combinations could lie in a plane or  on a line.

How is the author saying that the vectors and combinations could lie in a plane or on a line?  If we have 4 vectors, how is that their combination could lie on a line, while a 2 dimensional vector absolutely fills the two-dimensional plane? Cant it just end in a subset of the two-dimensional plane as well?

Comment: Note the "when $w$ is not on that line" clause. When $w$ *is* on the line spanned by $v$, then the combinations $cv + dw$ also do not fill the two-dimensional plane.

Comment: This is Strang’s style. You might look for amore rigorous textbook if you are unhappy with his style. It takes some underlying theory to answer your question. You don’t know dimension yet, but do you know about solving $Ax=b$ and how this relates to linear combinations of the columns of $A$?

Comment: @MishaLavrov When they are on the same line, I understand that they cannot fill the two dimensional plane. But if they are not on same line, how can we be sure that all combinations of $cv + dw$ fill the two dimensional plane **without any holes**

Comment: @TedShifrin I do not know how to solve $Ax = b$. Would you recommend any book that you mention of? I am little stumped by the book as well. I see assertions without theory backing it. I see vague statements with some details left out. And those proofless assertions and ill defined statements (e.g he doesn't mention that c and d are real numbers)  prevent me from moving forward

Comment: @Ravi I guess first you need to understand why a linear space can never have holes in it. When you take the span of two vectors, it is always a linear subspace (either by definition or through a straightforward proof). Remember that, once you know any vector $v$ lies in a subspace $V$, then any multiple of $v$ also lies in that subspace. There will never be something resembling a hole in a vector space, because each line which passes through that hole would be completely in or completely out of the subspace (except for the origin, which is always there).

Comment: I am fond of my own books, but they are far from freely available. However, you might find my YouTube lectures (pick and choose the ones dealing with linear algebra), linked in my profile, more theoretical and precise.

Comment: Also I might as well mention that 3blue1brown has excellent videos on linear algebra and other topics on youtube. He is not actually a research mathematician, but he has remarkable ways of understanding things and is a bit of a magician with communicating his understanding with computer animation.

Comment: Any or most university level introductory text on linear algebra should cover this concept with more or less rigor.
I'll try to write or find an explanation on a Precalculus level if I can find the time.  No Calculus or higher level math needed.

Comment: where in the text does Strang mention this property?

Comment: I think the key to the whole this what @TedShifrin mentioned about $Ax =b$. Even though I know that an equation of a line y=mx+c fills a whole line, I never understood how it plays an important role here. I saw 3blue1brown video on the topic and understood what all this actually meant.

Comment: 3blue1brown actually answers this exact question, which makes me think that this must have been a question many students face. Not taking it head-on in a Linear Algebra text book is a missed opportunity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P=<e, f>$ represent any point or vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ also denoted $\mathbb{R}x\mathbb{R} $.
**Goal:** Show that for any $V=<v_x,v_y>, W=<w_x,w_y>\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and V is not a multiple of W, there exists scalars, $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P=cV+dW$

Note: If V and W point in different directions, then they are *not* scalar multiples of each other.

The goal can be written as a vector equation.
$$cV+dW= P$$
It only remains to show that c and d exist which make the equation true.
Rewriting into two equations it becomes
$$\begin{align}
cv_x+dw_x&=e \text{ and }\\ 
cv_y+dw_y&=f\\
\text{        see Note 2 below}
\end{align}$$
Drop out the c term, by multiplying the 2nd equation by $\frac{-v_x}{v_y}$ and adding to the first equation.

$$\begin{align}
cv_x+dw_x&=e \text{ and }\\ 
-cv_x-dw_y\frac{v_x}{v_y}&=-\frac{v_x}{v_y}f  \\
dw_x-dw_y\frac{v_x}{v_y}&=e-\frac{v_x}{v_y}f
\end{align}$$

Because V and W are not scalar multiples of each other, it is possible to show $w_x-w_y\frac{v_x}{v_y}\neq0$

$$\begin{align}
d\left(w_x-w_y\frac{v_x}{v_y}\right)&=e-\frac{v_x}{v_y}f\\
d&=\frac{e-\frac{v_x}{v_y}f}{w_x-w_y\frac{v_x}{v_y}}\\
\end{align}$$
Therefore d exists.
**The reader can use this value of d to find c.**
In conclusion, after showing that c exists, for an arbitrarily chosen $P\in \mathbb{R}^2$, a solution exists to $cV+dW= P$ which means any point P can be reached by some linear combination of V and W.

Note 1: This is not intended to be a formal proof.  A formal proof should also deal with the cases $v_x$ or $v_y=0$, elaborate on the denominator of d$\neq 0$ and possibly the numerator of the d solution being zero, etc. among other details.  In the case of the numerator being zero, the point is on the line with cV, vector through the origin.

Note 2: In the two dimensional case, when V and W are not scalar multiples, there is a much simpler logical flow.
**A.** V and W are not scalar multiples implies
**B.** The two vectors, V and W, are linearly independent.
**C.** A 2x2 matrix with linearly independent rows always has an inverse.
**D.** The linear system above has a solution.

Comment: Are you familiar with the notation, $\mathbb{R}^2$, which represents the x-y plane?
$\leq$ and $\geq$ notation for points or vectors?
Is there any detail or *point*, (pun intended) which is unclear?

Comment: Note 3: This is much simpler to show in matrix notation, but I don't know how familiar or comfortable you with it, especially with lots of symbols for elements of the matrix.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer, especially to add vector notation, formalize it so it is a valid proof, add paragraph breaks, etc.

Comment: It logically makes sense. I'm going to accept this as the answer as I requested proof. But thinking through this for some more time geometrically, it made sense. E.g a vector can fill every point in that line based on a scalar. The other vector just moves the location of this vector, essentially painting the entire plane.